# How to recover files from unallocated partition?

Tags: partition-recovery

I tried installing linux mint 17 from live usb, in the process my windows partition got overwritten as a result I lost all my important files. I am not able to boot windows 7.

I used the cmd sudo fdisk-l...

```
Disk /dev/sda: 320.1 GB, 320072933376 bytes
255 heads,sk /dev/sda: 320.1 GB, 320072933376 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 38913 cylinders, total 625142448 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x0001b31c

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1            2048    20000767     9999360   83  Linux
/dev/sda2        20002814    92200959    36099073    5  Extended
/dev/sda5        20002816    92200959    36099072   83  Linux

WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/sdb'! The util fdisk doesn't support GPT. Use GNU Parted.


Disk /dev/sdb: 7803 MB, 7803174912 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 948 cylinders, total 15240576 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x25b7026a

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1   *           0     2603519     1301760    0  Empty
/dev/sdb2           74148       78691        2272   ef  EFI (FAT-12/16/32)

WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/sdb1'! The util fdisk doesn't support GPT. Use GNU Parted.


Disk /dev/sdb1: 1333 MB, 1333002240 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 162 cylinders, total 2603520 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x25b7026a

     Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1p1   *           0     2603519     1301760    0  Empty
/dev/sdb1p2           74148       78691        2272   ef  EFI (FAT-12/16/32)
```

Its does not show any NTFS partition...

Output of `df -h` command

```
mint@mint ~ $ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/cow            895M   88M  807M  10% /
udev            884M  8.0K  884M   1% /dev
tmpfs           179M  1.3M  178M   1% /run
/dev/sdb        1.3G  1.3G     0 100% /cdrom
/dev/loop0      1.2G  1.2G     0 100% /rofs
none            4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           895M  4.0K  895M   1% /tmp
none            5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
none            895M   76K  895M   1% /run/shm
none            100M   44K  100M   1% /run/user
/dev/sr1         76M   76M     0 100% /media/mint/Idea Net Setter
```

Comment: **Why are you using fdisk despite the fact the tool clearly indicates it does not support GPT partitions?**  This does not seem like a serious question based on that fact alone.

Answer (score 0):

Do **not** do anything else in the disk, or you'll lose your files forever!
If you have the possibility of making a full disk image of those 320 GB to somewhere else, do it, with `dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/sdz` (`sda` being the source drive and `sdz` being the destination).

Since not only the partition table was written, but the partitions were used, you're already in bad shape. No backups, I guess?

Give us the output of `df -h` to see how much might be salvageable.

I'd recommend you to boot from a Linux live CD, and run [PhotoRec](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec) and [The Sleuth Kit](http://www.sleuthkit.org/) on your hard drive. It should recover a good portion of your data, but make sure you *do not let them write the files over the hard drive*, or you'll overwrite the data you're trying to recover.
Take a look at [this](http://www.sleuthkit.org/informer/sleuthkit-informer-3.txt).